# android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in android-studio

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions

I want to know from where my app is installed *(who installed my app)*.

I need to use `getInstallerPackageName()`. And This method need to `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission. But this permission is **not grant** by *the system*.

[image: this is a image]
Returns `null` in all above methods.

1. **What way do you suggest to solve the problem?**
2. **What other way do you suggest for this?**

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android INSTALL\_PACKAGES Permission and Non-PlayStore Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553138/android-install-packages-permission-and-non-playstore-apps)

Comment: No, thanks. I know that it is not possible to use the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission for third-party programs. I am looking for a way to grant this permission. can i ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using this permission:
it probably will result in your app getting removed from google play store

You should be using REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES. The INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is not allowed to be used by third party apps according to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES

See also: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-it-safer-to-get-apps-on-android-o.html?m=1

update ([src](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295?hl=en)):

> Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions, including the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, which allows an application to request installing packages. Apps targeting API level 26 or newer must hold this permission in order to use Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE or the PackageInstaller API.

Comment: Thanks. Can I call function `getInstallerPackageName()` with permission `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` and get non-`null` content?

Comment: Still don't think so, also It is possible that google play will change it's policy and you will need to rewrite your code, if I were you I would just try to use the display name of the ContactsContract.Profile

Answer (score 0):

You can use PackageManager's `getInstallerPackageName()` API without the need for INSTALL_PACKAGES. The android docs suggest that it is deprecated since API level 30 but:

- android docs suggest [Package Manager's getInstallSourceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallSourceInfo(java.lang.String)) instead, and the `installSourceInfo's` `getOriginatingPackageName()` to get the desired info. However, only `getOriginatingPackageName()` needs INSTALL_PACKAGES.
- `getOriginatingPackageName()` is only available on Android R and above, so I guess Google may close one eye to the usage of the deprecated `getInstallerPackage()` for a while. And for that, you don't need the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.
- practical testing/usage in apps finds that `getInstallerPackageName()` still works as desired, and without the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.